# Increasing new attribute when element clicked with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that has 5 td tags in it.

```
<tr id="rows">
    <td x="111" y="1" col="1" row="1">
      <div class="marge-col"></div>
    </td>
    <td x="1" y="1" col="2" row="1">
        <div class="marge-col"></div>
    </td>
    <td x="1" y="1" col="3" row="1">
        <div class="marge-col"></div>
    </td>
    <td x="1" y="1" col="4" row="1">
      <div class="marge-col"></div>
    </td>
    <td x="1" y="1" col="5" row="1">
        <div class="marge-col"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want a click on the `div.marge-col` td tag(parent of clicked div) to increase `attr('x')` one value(for example, when I click on `first.merge-col` parent tag(td) increase x attribute and change value to 2)
I cannot do it.
This is my jquery code, but it's not working.
When I click on first `div.marge-col` console shows me `**11**`!!! Why??? (1+1=11???)

```
$(document).on('click','#rows td .marge-col',function(){
                    console.log('col');
                    $(this).parent().attr('x',$(this).parent().attr('x')+1);
                    console.log($(this).parent().attr('x'));
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the attribute is a string not a number, use `pasrseInt` to use it as a number, when you add a string and a number the number is treated as a string and concatenated to the other string.

```
$(this).parent().attr('x',parseInt($(this).parent().attr('x'))+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `+` operator concatenates strings as well as performs addition with numbers, and an attribute value is always a strong, even if it's a numeric character. So, try ensuring that the "number" is a number before incrementing it:

```
$(this).parent().attr('x', function (i,x){
    return parseInt(x) + 1;
});
```